# Julia LsqFit is giving wrong results whereas I am able to get correct results using scipy.optimize (almost equal to exp results)

Tags: julia

I tried to fit Magnetization vs Magnetic field using law of approach to saturation magnetization using Julia, but not able to get correct results. The parameters, p[2] is showing the same values what I assumed. whereas the same procedure when I tried with scipy I am able to get good results.

```
using DataFrames, CSV
df=CSV.read("X00.csv"; delim=",")
xdata=df[!, 1]
ydata=df[!, 2]
using Plots
using LsqFit
@. model(x, p) = p[1]*(1-(p[2]/x)-(p[4]*p[3]^2 /(p[3]^2 *x^2)))
p0=[97.0, 231.0, 250000.0, 0.076]

fit = curve_fit(model, xdata, ydata, p0)

beta_fit = fit.param

yfit = model(xdata, fit.param)
println(beta_fit)
scatter(xdata, ydata, label="data", grid=false)
plot!(xdata, yfit, label="model", grid=false)
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: You have asked the same question twice. Please remove one copy.